# A pain-free way of debugging a "plug-in" application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm about to start developing a desktop application (WPF) based on a "plugin" architecture, and was going to use MEF (and its `DirectoryCatalog`) to discover and load plugin assemblies. We're going to be developing many plugins, so it seems sensible to keep them in separate VS solutions rather than bloat the "core" application solution, but having only ever worked on single, standalone solutions, I suspect this is going to make debugging a bit tricky. I'm using VS2013 if that makes a difference.

I'm assuming that I'll still be able to step into a plugin in scenarios where the "core" application calls a method in that plugin? And I'm guessing that once in there, I'll be able to set breakpoints in those source code files that have been "visited"? But what if I want to add a breakpoint to a different source code file - one that *hasn't* been visited while stepping-through? How can I open that file? In a single solution I could just open it via Solution Explorer, but not (I'm guessing) when it's in a separate assembly.

I'm trying to pre-empt any problems I might have with this multi-solution approach, and wondered if VS had any clever features to simplify some of this stuff. Having separate solutions also means first compiling the plugin solution(s) that I want to test, then compiling and running the "core" application solution. While it's only a couple of extra mouse clicks, are there (again) any VS features that could help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two ways to do this.

The more comfortable option:

**1. You can add the external solution to the core solution.**

[Walkthrough: Adding an existing Visual Studio solution to another solution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/habibh/archive/2009/06/24/walkthrough-adding-an-existing-visual-studio-solution-to-another-solution.aspx)

By doing this you can organize your solution to reference the code and still keep each plugin solution separate at the same time.

You just reference those plugin solutions from your core solution that you currently want to work on. Also, using this approach you can organize the other solutions just like you would with normal projects and move thembetween virtual solutios folders to your liking until you have the most adequate folder structure.

Quote from the article:

> The nice thing about this approach is that not only are all the
>   projects now in one solution but at any time, you can open the
>   separate solutions without impacting the "master" solution and vice
>   versa.

The files in the references solution can be opened and edited just like any other file from your "normal" projects, and of course, you can set breakpoint like in any other code file, too.

This way you can both edityour code **and** step through it, which I personally find much more convenient than switching and attaching to multiple processes.

**2. Add the PDB files.**

Put the DLLs with their corresponding PDBs of those plugins you want to debug into a folder and configure your core application to use that folder for the `DirectoryCatalog`. This enables you to step into the plugin code, but you will not be able to edit them.

Comment: Your approach (option 1) seems like it will be better suited to how I'll be developing the application. While I can see @Dominic Kexel's approach being useful in some scenarios, I've accepted your answer!

Answer (score 3):

This is a common scenario and not tricky at all.

In the project properties of your plug-ins, go to `Debug -> Start Action`  and set `Start external program` to the executable of your core application.

This way, you only have to compile your core application once (probably using a build script that just builds *everything*), and debugging a plug-in will start the core application with the debugger attached and you can debug the plug-in (as soon as your core apllication loads the plug-in assembly).

Also keep in mind that you can dettach the debugger from the running application, switch to another instance of Visual Studio with another solution opened, and again attach to your running application. This comes in handy if you e.g. debug your plug-in and want to set or use existing break points in your core application.

As long as Visual Studio is able to find the debugging symbols (the *.pdb files), stepping through the code of e.g. your core application while debugging your plug-in is also no problem.

Answer (score 0):

@Andrew
Regarding debugging, it shouldn't be an issue as long as you drop the .pdb files with assembly in directory which you are using as DirectoryCatalog.

Regarding building plugin solution before Core- as you have 1 build file for each solution, you should check if you can write msbuild commands in a .bat file to get it executed one after other.

Answer (score 0):

Besides all the above suggestions, another way to debug is to attach your addin solution to the running core process. [Attach to Running Processes with the Visual Studio Debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s68z0b3.aspx)